# Can my XSD schema be set up so namespace elements appear as global to validated XML?

Tags: xml, xsd

Given this XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
           targetNamespace="ABC" xmlns:abc="ABC">

  <xs:complexType name="thing">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="NAME" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="DESCRIPTION" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:element name="things">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="thing" type="abc:accident" 
                    maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I am having issues validating the following against it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<things>
  <thing>
    <NAME>Zaphod Beeblebrox</NAME>
    <DESCRIPTION>Just this guy</DESCRIPTION>
  </thing>
</things>
```

I think it's all down to namespaces... I only added a namespace to my XSD since I was getting errors about "namespace ''" in the XSD validation. But I don't control the XML to insert some sort of namespace reference.

Is there some simple way that `<things>` in the XML will be validated as `<abc:things>` - or a way to exclude namespaces in the XSD altogether?

Answer (score 1):

**If your XML is set,**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<things xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="try.xsd">
  <thing>
    <NAME>Zaphod Beeblebrox</NAME>
    <DESCRIPTION>Just this guy</DESCRIPTION>
  </thing>
</things>
```

**and it does not use namespaces, then simply write your XSD not to use namespaces:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:complexType name="thing">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="NAME" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="DESCRIPTION" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:element name="things">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="thing" type="thing"
                    maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

**The above XSD will successfully validate the above XML.**